# Usage of "this" to refer to a concept

Tags: word-usage

I wrote:

> But the first stage is to acquire a suitable image from the middle frame of each pallet car.  In the next section, .....

Which is better for the blank

1. we propose a method for this purpose.
2. we propose a method to do this.
3. we propose a method for this.
4. we propose a method for it.

Sometimes I don't know which noun is suitable to refer to an already mentioned thing. then I may just use "this". Is it common in writing in English? or is it better to always find a suitable noun after "this", like *this purpose, this task, this job*. what are common words for these occasions?

Comment: #2 is the clearest, since by mentioning "to do" it refers the reader back to the infinitive phrase in the preceding clause, establishing without any doubt the antecedent to **this**.

Comment: As the above comment states, #2 is the best.#3 and 4 get your point across but result in a little ambiguity that a native will have no trouble understanding.

Comment: (cont.) What you are describing is a "task" or "job", not a "purpose". "We propose a method for this purpose" answers the question "Why are you proposing a method?" It suggests that the following sentences will contain information about "why" you are proposing a method, not "what" that method is.

Answer (score 1):

> We propose a method to accomplish this.

"Accomplish" is a more formal equivalent of "do".

This is a nice example showing that you do not need a noun after "this".  You could read up on "demonstrative pronouns".